# HSQLDB how to manually insert records

Tags: hsqldb

My question is how can I manually add records to hsqldb database. I mean using command line or some client. I know I can use hsqldb manager but I cannot execute any query with it. It says that there is no table of specified name. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was I wasnt connecting to actual database file :)
HSQLDB Manager works :p

Cheers